# Thermodynamic equilibrium criterion

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

I have a question about a characterization of thermodynamic equilibrium as given on German wiki article: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamisches_Gleichgewicht#Abgeschlossenes_System

What does it state? Let $S=S(U, V, N)$ the entropy and the expression $S=S(U, V, N)$ make sense as well a state with macroscopical parameters $U,V,N$ is in thermodynamical equilibrium. The claim is

> "Ein abgeschlossenes System befindet sich im thermodynamischen Gleichgewicht, wenn seine Entropie $S$ maximal ist. Entsprechend gilt, für das Differential
>
> $$dS=0$$

Translated that means

> A closed system is in thermodynamic equilibrium when its entropy $S$ is at a maximum. For the differential this means $dS=0$.

And the last condition I not understand. By definition writing $S= S(U,V,N)$ (or for any other arbitrary thermodynamic potential e.g. internal energy $U(S,V,N)$ or free Helmholtz $F(T,V,N)$)

makes *only* sense *if* the given state parametrized by macro parameters $U,V,N$ *is* already in thermodynamic equilibrium. Otherwise, $S= S(U,V,N)$ don't make any sense as a thermodynamical system that is *not* in a thermodynamic equilibrium is too complex to be described by only three independent macro parameters $U, V,N$ and futhermore the concept of associating a thermodynamical potential to a state *only* works if one consider a state beeing already in equilibrium.

Therefore what is $dS=0$ (or more precisely how to interpret it in this context?) and why does it make sense to use it as characterization of equilibrium?

The only way I'm familar how the differential $dS$ is used in thermodynamics is explaned in following setting. We start with a state parametrized by $(U_1,V_1,N_1)$ that is *already* in thermodynamic equilibrium and then we start a certain thermodynamical process (reversible or irreversible) that finally brings the system in another state $(U_2,V_2,N_2)$ that is also in a new thermodynamical equilibrium after a long time.

The point is that *how* we pass from $(U_1,V_1,N_1)$ to $(U_2,V_2,N_2)$ we don't know precisely as in nature we pass during the process non equilibrium states that we can't describe with our formalism. One possible ansatz is to consider it a sequence of  [quastatical processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_process) such that each intermediate state is assumed to be also in thermodynamical equilibrium. This is of course a strong idealisation.

With this idealization passing from $(U_1,V_1,N_1)$ to $(U_2,V_2,N_2)$ can be indeed visualized as a curve in Phase space as long as we consider it as a quasistatic process.

then indeed also the expression $dS= S(U_2,V_2,N_2)-S(U_1,V_1,N_1) $ make sense.

But in this case it makes no sense to use $dS=0$ as characterization of a state beeing in themodynamic equilibrium as by $dS$ we consider *allways* diferences of enropies of states that are already in equilibriums.

Does anybody have an idea how the "characterization thermodynamic of quilibrium" $dS=0$ should here be understood and what is the error in my reasonings above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us imagine a box of gas in equilibrium with volume $V$ and energy $U$. And let there be a heat conducting piston that divides the volume into two parts, $V_1 = αV$ and $V_2 = (1 − α)V$. They are at some common temperature $T_1 = T_2 = T$, but not necessarily at a common pressure. The system is forced into equilibrium despite this due to a constraint, holding the piston in place. Since entropy is additive, the entropy of the combined system is just the sum:
$$S=S_1\left(V_1\right)+S_2\left(V_2\right)=S(αV)+S\left((1 − α)V\right)$$
Now we let the piston move. It may no longer stay in place and α could change. But where will it settle down? Here is where the maximum entropy comes in. We are told it will settle down at the value that maximizes S:
$$0=dS =dS_1+dS_2\\
\frac{\partial S_1}{\partial V_1}dV_1+ \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial V_2}dV_2\\
=\left(\frac{P_1}{T_1}-\frac{P_2}{T_2}\right) Vd\alpha\\
0=\left(\frac{P_1-P_2}{T}\right)d\alpha
$$
which is the correct physical answer: in equilibrium, when S is maximized, the pressures will be equal. So the principle of maximum entropy means that **when a system held in equilibrium by a constraint becomes free to explore new equilibrium states due to the removal of the constraint, it will pick the one which maximizes S**. In this example, where its options are parametrized by α, it will pick$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial\alpha}=0$$

Comment: Yes, this example reveals exactly the point that confuses me. As you said we start with a system (in our case box of gas) that is in equilibrium with fixed $V,U$ consisting of two subsystems with volumes $V_1= \alpha V, V_2 = (1- \alpha) V$ where at first $\alpha$ is fixed as the piston is fixed at begin; thus it's mathematically a constrain. Thus the entropy $S(U,V)$ at the beginning  is maximal with *respect the given constrain $\alpha$*. Now we let piston move (= throw away the constrain $\alpha$) and waiting still the new system becomes an equilibrium.

Comment: Mathematically as you say it's a extremal problem and this is exacly what confuses me: over which argument space lives $S$ *while we maximize it* with respect $\alpha$ ? The naive phase space $(\{V_1, V_2, U, N) \vert V_1+V_2 =V \}$? If yes, then I don't understand the point, since in the phase space every state hast to be an equilibrium space, otherwise it cannot be expressed in a such few number of macroparameters.

Comment: More concretly the following point confuses me: on the one hand when we vary $\alpha$ we „fluctuate“ in the phase space and physics tells that the equilibrium state is exactly the state for which $S$ becomes maximal. On the other hnd every state in phase space is an equilibrium state as otherwise it cannot be expressed in a such few number of macroparameters. Since physics tells that only a equilibrium state can be discribed by such „compact“ set of macro paramters like $(U,V,N)$. Thus this extremal problem sounds like „we maximize a function in order to find unique equilibrium

Comment: state although every state in phase space is an equilibrium by argument above“. This of course absurd and that’s exactly what confuses me. Do you see my thinking error at this point?

Comment: Possibly I miss the whole point but would like to explain my unterstanding of the whole story with respect the $dS=0$ conditions as possibly it will reveal my thinking error that I have in order to understand your answer. Firstly the entropy $S$ (or any other thermodynamic potential) can generally be associated to every state (independent if it is in equilibrium or not). The *difference* is that if we have such a state in non equilibrium then it can only be described not by tree macroparameters $(U,V,N)$ but a huge number of further parameters,

Comment: , ie the state is described by $(U,V,N, P_1, P_2,...)$ and to this state we theoretically can associate an entropy function that is ig complicated (and time dependent) as long as the considered state is non equilibrium; concretly $S=S(T, U,V,N, P_1, P_2,..., \alpha_1, \alpha_2,...)$ where $\alpha_i$ are given constrains. Now (I think) that the joke is that *if* we know that the state is in equilibrium the entropy highly simplifies to a function with small number of parameters $S(U, V,N, \alpha_1, \alpha_2,...)$. For sake of simplicity say $S$ has only one constrain $\alpha$ as in your example.

Comment: And in our case if we start as in your example by system in equilibrium, ie with entropy $S(U,V,N, \alpha)$ and now throw the constrain $\alpha$ away we maximize not only $S(\alpha V)+ S((1- \alpha)V)$ but the weird $S(T, U, \alpha V, N, P_1, P_2,...)+S(T, U, (1-\alpha) V, N, P_1', P_2',...), T \to \infty$ with respect to $\alpha$. That is during the "fluctuation" $dS=dS_1+dS_2$ the arguments of $S_1+S_2$ are not living in naive phase space (which alows as points only equilibrium states and as paths only quasi statical processes)

Comment: but in the weird $U, V,N, P_1,P_2,...)$ ("space of all possible states").

Comment: I mean in summary, the only point that confuses me is when we vary $S$ with respect to $\alpha$, in which space live arguments of the „fluctuating“ entropy function $S+ \delta S(\alpha)$?

Comment: think of it this way. Say we don’t remove the constraint fully but loosen it a bit. Then it moves and we constrain it again with some force. We can repeat the process until we reach a point where we don’t have to apply force to keep the constrain from moving. This is the final state. And if we do it slow enough, at each instant the system is in equilibrium.

Comment: ...and this way of thinking about it is exactly what literature calles "quasi statical", right?

Comment: Yes. That’s right. Since $U$ is a state variable, it doesn’t matter which path you took to reach the particular set of $U, V, N$

Comment: so maybe in order to connect what I wrote above together with this say "quasi statical maximization": that "mess-up" what I tried to describe in my "Possibly I miss blabla..."-comment can be seen as a kind "what happens" between an infinitesimal "loosen it a bit the constrain and then  we constrain it again with some force"-cycle, right?

Comment: Yes. That’s the only way we can describe the system with few parameters. Namely the system is in equilibrium.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I think slowly I develop a certain intuition what is going on. One last remark: in his answer below Alexander says that $dS$ can be used in static and dynamic cases. The static one was exactly what you explained in your answer. By dynamic one he explaines that "we change the macro state..." Do you have an idea what he means? In mean if a state is in equilibrium than it not changes without any change of external conditions. Or can this dynamic case seen again as in "constrain" problem.

Comment: That is the ssystem has is in state $(U,V,N)$ only *because the presence* of certain inner constrain and now if we remove it then the system fluctuates – again, quasi statically by the same logic as in our previous discussion – on a certain path, on which as states have same $S$ ? Is this what Alexander possibly mean ?

Comment: Yes. The parameters $V,P,S,U$ are all well defined only in equilibrium. So in order to use then meaningfully we need to be in equilibrium at each instant.

Answer (score 1):

The criterion $dS=0$ characterizes equilibrium, as by *assumption* equilibrium is the maximum entropy state, thus any fluctuation from the state will result in decrease in entropy. Thus, from Fermat's theorem (stationary points) you get that the derivative of $S$ at this state is zero.

This rule is used differently for static cases (to find equilibrium) and dynamic cases (move from one to another). For static cases you assume perfect knowledge of your *single* macro state $(U,V,N)$ and calculate the entropy consistent with this macroscopic configuration. Notice the assumption of closed system in the wiki definition, it means setting specific $(U,V,N)$ and finding appropriate equilibrium. For dynamic cases you change your macro state $(U,V,N)$. Notice that $S(U,V,N)$ is single valued function, that is - single value for any $(U,V,N)$, but it doesn't mean that many different states $(U,V,N)$ cannot have the same value. By proper adjustment of the macroscopic parameters you can pass through equilibrium states. That means that if you stop the process at any time - the system remains there (as opposed to perturbing the system out of equilibrium, which starts the time dependent process of equilibration)

Modern definition of equilibrium is by property of [detailed balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance), that is, the phase space being static, without probability currents*. Proper modern treatment of the topic comes from perspective of non-equilibrium statistical mechanics, with tools such as Fokker-Planck equation and stochastic processes.

*Notice that non-vanishing probability currents can still result in static distribution. In this case the state is not called "equilibrium" but a "non-equilibrium steady state".

Comment: The usage for *static* case I probably undrstand. Do you refer here to such kind of problem where $U,V,N$ are fixed, considered system is isolated/closed and in equilbrium and we asking if for example if this already imply eg that everywhere in the system the presure or temperature most be equal. That is we split the system in two parts $(U_1, V_1,N_1)$ and $(U_2, V_2,N_2)$ with conditions $U=U_1 +U_2$ ans the same for $V$ & $N$ and then derive $T_1=T_2$ and $p_1=p_2$ by the static ansatz & aditivity $0=dS= dS_1(U_1, V_1,N_1)+dS_2(U_2, V_2,N_2)=...$ That's what you mean by static case, right?

Comment: Your explanation on *dynamic* case I not fully understand. As you said we start with macro state $(U,V,N)$ and want to change it. Do I understand you correctly that the motivation in dynamic case is to obtain informations about $S$ by going throught the phase space configured by variables $U,V,N$ from starting "point" $(U_1, V_1,N_1)$ to another one *along a path in phase space (thus the whole time quasistatical; otherwise this "path" not make any sense) which not change $S$, thus only along equipotential paths?

Comment: And the motivation is that if certain paths are "alowed" we gain new information about the shape of $S$? Is this what you mean or did I misunderstood you?